# Sarchkick issue: A and (B or C)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, searchkick

**I have this query:**

```
City.search(@query, where: {
  activated: true,
  available: true,
  or: [
    [
      { country_id: [92, 95] },
      { admin_code_id: [922, 927] }
    ]
  ]
}).
```

But i think the where hash is not good, because the thing i want to do is:

`activated` **AND** `available` **AND** **(**`country_id` **IN** `[92, 95]` **OR** `admin_code_id` **IN** `[922, 927]`**)**

I tried a lot of different syntax, but nothing work for me.

Answer (score 0):

For your query, you can use Squeel: https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/squeel

Query:

```
where{(activated == true) & (available == true) & ((country_id.in([92, 95])) | (country_id.in([922, 927])))}
```